# Problems with conditional PackageReference & ProjectReference nodes in .csproj files in Visual Studio, but not with dotnet build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration, nuget, csproj

I have 3 projects:  A, B & C.

Project C depends on projects A & B.  I have C.csproj setup so that in Debug configuration, projects A & B are referenced as ProjectReferences, however in Release configuration, projects A & B are referenced according to their published package files with PackageReferences:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\A\A.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\B\B.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  <PackageReference Include="A" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This works perfectly as I would expect using `dotnet build -c Debug`, for instance (it references projects A & B just fine and code changes in those projects that aren't published to their local nugets are brought into C as expected).  However this seemingly randomly fails when I build in Visual Studio.  In this case, most of the time, when I build in `Debug` configuration in Visual Studio, it appears to be referencing the nuget packages, rather than the project references.  Accordingly, when I 'go to definition' in Visual Studio for code defined in A or B, it shows me the definitions in the nuget assemblies, rather than taking me to the appropriate code files in the projects themselves.  When I clear out my local nuget cache `dotnet nuget locals all -c` and delete my local nuget repo, when I build in Visual Studio in Debug configuration, I get build errors like:

```
/Users/me/repo/C/C.csproj:  error NU1101: Unable to find package A.  No packages exist with this in in source(s): local feed, nuget.org.
```

This shouldn't happen (and doesn't happen with `dotnet build -c Debug`), as those PackageReferences should be ignored in Debug configuration!

Any ideas?  How can I accomplish configuration-dependent package/project referencing in Visual Studio?

EDIT for explanation:

I have a solution (a microservice architecture) where multiple projects depend on *potentially multiple versions* of a set of component app libraries.   During day-to-day development, though, I don't want to have to manually bump app library versions, publish a nuget package, then bump PackageReference versions, for every single component library change I make.  However, when a microservice is actually deployed, it needs to reference a specific version a component app library (i.e. PackageReference).  ProjectReferences will not work here, because multiple microservices may reference different versions of the same app libraries (plus, PackageReferences make containerizing each microservice a lot easier).

This scheme works fine using the dotnet cli tools, but for some unknown reason does not work in Visual Studio 2019 (Mac).

Comment: When you pack a project, NuGet will convert project references into package dependencies, just as package references are. Are you sure you need to switch between package and project references based on configuration?

Comment: yes, I'm sure that I need to switch between package and project references based on configuration.  Hmm, unless I've missed something and ProjectReferences are somehow versionable?

Comment: The dependency version of a package is the version of the project when/if it packed itself. Give it a go, use only project references, set each project to a different version, pack the projects, then inspect the nupkgs generated.

Comment: No, this is does not work for my use-case.  See my edit to the OP for details.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=41 That's not surprising as VS or VS for Mac MSBuild support has less flexibility on what syntax should appear in the project files (conditional sections are usually problematic). But you can report to Microsoft and see if they'd like to fix.

Comment: I switched to Jetbrains Rider and it works perfectly.